# Python-How to read multiple files simultaneously and keep records of the data

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python. I have 10 input files with the format shown below. Each file contains measurement data for a receiver (receivers 1-10). Each receiver has measurements from 10 transmitters (transmitters 1-10). The files are ordered chronologically with time in seconds.

I want to read the 10 files simultaneously line by line. As the files are read, I want to collect 4 measurements from each file for each transmitter and average those values to get a 4 second averaged value per receiver-transmitter pair. I want to keep track of each averaged value for each receiver-transmitter pair. Once I have collected the 4 second averaged values for all transmitters for a specific receiver, I want to average those values to get an averaged value for that receiver. I also want to keep track of these averaged values (time average and measurement average) and to which receiver they belong to.

I can't load these files into memory because the files are huge (on the order of gigabytes). Keeping all the averaged values in memory is also an issue because of the size of the files. I only want to keep an hour's worth of data for each receiver-transmitter pair for the averaged values in memory. Once I have an hour's worth of averaged values, as a new averaged value is computed, I want to discard the oldest one.

I was thinking that dictionaries might be the best way to keep track of the data.

How can I accomplish the task above?

Input File:

Column Format:Time (seconds) Transmitter# Measurement

```
 0.0  1 2.4779E+02
 0.0  2 2.8147E+02
 0.0  3 2.7437E+02
 0.0  4 2.6661E+02
 0.0  5 2.2637E+02
 0.0  6 2.1457E+02
 0.0  7 2.3750E+02
 0.0  8 2.9573E+02
 0.0  9 2.7339E+02
 0.0 10 2.4982E+02
 1.0  1 2.1086E+02
 1.0  2 2.7459E+02
 1.0  3 2.1569E+02
 1.0  4 2.0018E+02
 1.0  5 2.8732E+02
 1.0  6 2.2633E+02
 1.0  7 2.2900E+02
 1.0  8 2.6883E+02
 1.0  9 2.4482E+02
 1.0 10 2.8314E+02
 2.0  1 2.6987E+02
 2.0  2 2.5946E+02
 2.0  3 2.8195E+02
 2.0  4 2.3097E+02
 2.0  5 2.2592E+02
 2.0  6 2.5316E+02
 2.0  7 2.5562E+02
 2.0  8 2.5892E+02
 2.0  9 2.1258E+02
 2.0 10 2.5791E+02
```

Comment: What have you _tried_ so far? Don't worry about loading files into memory: Python's `open()` creates a file _streaming_ interface, so you're only reading one line of a file into memory at a time with `readline()` (and automatically removing what came before), rather than all of it at once (though you can certainly force it to read all of it at once). Your basic issue is already solved, so nothing is actually preventing you from doing this the way you want to using a naive approach.

Comment: @markm if you've got any answer, please mark it and close as it would help other members. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can used the FileObject.readline() in python to access files parallely.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Open a file
fo = open("foo.txt", "rw+")
fo1 = open("foo1.txt", "rw+")

line = fo.readline()
print "Read Line from foo: %s" % (line)

line = fo1.readline()
print "Read Line from foo1: %s" % (line)

# Close opend file
fo.close()
fo1.close()
```

Similarly, you could use 10 objects for 10 different input files and use readline on each of them. Hope this helps.

For your problem statement, measurements from each file for each transmitter and average those values to get a 4 second averaged value per receiver-transmitter pair can be read. To keep track of each averaged value for each receiver-transmitter pair, create a Dictionary or a Custom List.Then build your logic for receiver to get the final result/value. But make sure, you delete the data from Dictionary/List once they're no longer needed.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A number of Python facilities will help:

- put the samples into a `defaultdict`, where each item is a list, keyed on the transmitter ID
- use `glob` to list out all the data files in your directory
- with `namedtuple`s we can give each bit of data a name, which is easier to read than a simple list or tuple

## open data files in parallel, store per-transmitter list of samples

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
averagetrans -- calculate receiver/transmitter averages
'''
import collections
import glob
import sys

ReceiverData = collections.namedtuple(
    'ReceiverData',
    ['path', 'time_sec', 'transmitter', 'measurement'])

def parse_data(path, line):
    words = line.rstrip().split()
    return ReceiverData(
        path=path,
        time_sec=words[0],
        transmitter=words[1],
        measurement=float(words[2]))


transmitter_data = collections.defaultdict(list)

files = dict((path, open(path))
             for path in glob.glob('receiver*.csv'))

while True:
    for rpath, rfile in files.iteritems():
        line = rfile.readline()
        if not line:
            sys.exit(0)
        datum = parse_data(rpath, line)

        cur_data = transmitter_data[datum.transmitter]
        # take most recent four samples
        cur_data.append(datum)
        cur_data = cur_data[-4:]

        average = sum(dat.measurement for dat in cur_data) / len(cur_data)

        print 'trans {}: average {}'.format(
                 datum.transmitter,
            average)
        # print '\t- data: {}'.format(cur_data)
```

## output with each transmitter's 4-sample average

```
trans 4: average 200.18
trans 1: average 247.79
trans 5: average 287.32
trans 2: average 281.47
trans 6: average 226.33
trans 3: average 274.37
trans 7: average 229.0
trans 4: average 233.395
trans 8: average 268.83
trans 5: average 256.845
trans 9: average 244.82
trans 6: average 220.45
trans 10: average 283.14
trans 7: average 233.25
trans 1: average 258.83
trans 8: average 282.28
trans 2: average 270.465
trans 9: average 259.105
trans 3: average 278.16
trans 10: average 266.48
trans 4: average 232.586666667
trans 1: average 242.84
trans 5: average 246.536666667
trans 2: average 271.84
trans 6: average 231.353333333
trans 3: average 257.336666667
trans 7: average 240.706666667
```